# Conditional initialization of objects

Tags: objective-c, polymorphism

I would like to have this code in Objective-C:

```
if (a == b) {
    Class1 *object = [[Class1 alloc] init];
} else {
    Class2 *object = [[Class2 alloc] init];
}
```

But these objects are not visible outside the IF-scope. Is there any method how to initialize objects inside IF-statement and use them outside IF? Class2 is subclass of Class1, so later I will use common properties of classes i.e. Class1 properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that `Class2` is a subclass, we can declare the variable outside as a `Class1` object:

```
Class1 *object;
if (a == b) {
    object = [[Class1 alloc] init];
} else {
    object = [[Class2 alloc] init];
}
```

We could also one-line it as such:

```
Class1 *object = (a == b) ? [[Class1 alloc] init] : [[Class2 alloc] init];
```

Now, in the current scope, the compiler will throw warnings if you try to call `Class2` methods on the object.  But you can also check later to be sure what sort of object it is:

```
if ([object isKindOfClass:[Class2 class]]) {
    Class2 *c2obj = (Class2 *)obj;
    // call class2 methods on `c2obj
}
```

You can still call the methods without the cast... but the compiler likes it better if you do it this way.

And this is only necessary for calling `Class2` methods/properties.  You don't have to cast either to call `Class1` methods or properties on `object`.

I actually commonly use this sort of approach in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` where I have a few different sorts of cells, but they all are subclasses of the same parent class and/or all conform to a common protocol.

Comment: I mark your question with green tick cause it was answered a bit earlier, but still, both answers are correct. Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 2):

How about simply

```
Class1* object;
if (a == b)
  object = [Class1 new];
else
  object = [Class2 new];
```